# View the original code of .NET controls

Tags: vb.net, background, controls

Is there any way to access/view the original code of vb.net controls? (Textbox, DataGridView,..)

I would like to look through the code to learn how the original painting procedures are done.

Appreciation for your help!

Comment: Here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a reflector like this:

- [ILSpy (Free)](http://ilspy.net/)
- [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

ILSpy Features

- Assembly browsing
- IL Disassembly
- Support C# 5.0 "async"
- Decompilation to C#
- Supports lambdas and 'yield return'
- Shows XML documentation
- Decompilation to VB
- Saving of resources
- Save decompiled assembly as .csproj
- Search for types/methods/properties (substring)
- Hyperlink-based type/method/property navigation
- Base/Derived types navigation
- Navigation history
- BAML to XAML decompiler
- Save Assembly as C# Project
- Find usage of field/method
- Extensible via plugins (MEF)
- Assembly Lists

**Edit**

To address the question in the comment:
[image: ILSpy]

1. Press the search button
2. Change the dropdown `Search for` to `Type`
3. Enter `Textbox` in the Search field
4. Scroll down and find the `Textbox` with namespace `System.Windows.Forms`. Click on the row
5. The decompiled syntax will be here

Comment: Thank you for your answer! ILSpy looks great. Could your tell me where I could find the classes controls in the TreeView of ILSpy? There is no entry like "System.Windows.Forms"

Comment: I appreciate your answer! Very well explained. Do you have a hint where I could find the painting procedures of controls? (e.g. a TextBox?) I am looking through all the onPaint and inherited onPaint procedures and cannot find where and how the painting is done.